# decent right-click emulation

Tags: input-methods, emulators

I'm using [aDOSbox](http://androiddosbox.appspot.com/) to play some classical games. This in turn uses SDL library, one of the thing this library does is emulate mouse. It's the same library, that is also used by [ScummVM](https://sites.google.com/site/scummvmandroid/).

I've got it set up to be quite usable for left-click (I'm using "tap or hold"), but I'm having trouble getting right-click to work decently. I'm using default settings, which is doing two finger tap. However, very often it'll get recognized two as single ones instead. The best option would be to use hardware button, however I'm using Galaxy S II, and all hardware buttons are reserved.

Any suggestion on best settings to use?

Answer (score 1):

A slide in a particular direction. Or may be a slide in multiple directions (say one slide to the right from the top left to top right, continued down from right top to right bottom). I don't know how effective it might be, but I guess worth a try.